# Excel VBA - adjust number of rows based on change in cell value

Tags: excel, vba

Could you please give me a hand with following problem:

I have a dataset in rows 106 to 109. In Cell A102, I have a value that's currently 3. Rows 103 to 105 are empty.

I'm looking for a VBA code that will change the number of empty rows below row 102 based on the cell value in A102.

For example: If I change A102 to 0, then rows 103-105 would be deleted, and my dataset would start in row 103. If I then change A102 to 8, then 8 rows would be inserted and the dataset would commence from row 111. And so on.

I have really no idea how to do this, so I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: Please see [ask] - show what you have tried and you have more chance of getting an answer that is useful.

Comment: Record a macro while adding/deleting rows. This will give you some foundation. Then, you will need to add a `variable` to express the number of rows. Then, tie it in to the `Worksheet_Change` event.  Start with those three bits, come back and post some code, and people will be more inclined to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you are after is this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim n As Integer
Dim n1 As Integer

'Do nothing if more than one cell is changed or content deleted

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Address = "$A$102" Then
        If IsNumeric(Target) Then
            n = 0

            While Range("A103").Offset(n, 0) = ""
                n = n + 1
            Wend

        End If

        For n1 = 1 To n
            Rows("103:103").Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Next

        For n1 = 1 To Range("A102")
            Rows("103:103").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Chris, this really helped. Thanks a lot :) As I have no idea how to approach this, I'm glad you were able to decipher my apparently unclear post. Cheers!