# How to dynamically insert/delete rows in Excel depending on the value of a cell (using VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Unfortunately, I have very little experience with VBA so I would like some help with a project.

I have an excel form that takes an integer in cell D10 (cells D10:I10 are merged), I will call this N.
I would like row 12 to be duplicated N times (including the cell contents and formatting), and for the number of rows to dynamically change as N is changed by the user.

[image]

I guess the answer should be similar to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343989/excel-vba-adjust-number-of-rows-based-on-change-in-cell-value), but I have had no luck trying to decipher it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and sorry for the basic nature of this question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43525799/insert-specific-number-of-rows) should help you more, pair that with a copy paste or if you're using the CopyOrigin of the Insert method just give the values over.

Edit to accommodate the dynamically changing part :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("D10"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Dim N As Integer, lRow As Long
        N = Target.Value
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If N = 0 Then 
            N = 1 'We don't want to delete the base-row
            Target.Value = 1
        End If
        lRow = Me.Range("B" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim rngCountry As Range
        Set rngCountry = Me.Range("B12:B" & lRow).Find("Country", LookIn:=xlValues)

        Dim rng As Range, rNeed As Long
        Set rng = Me.Range("B12:I12")
        rNeed = (rngCountry.Row - 12 - N) * -1
        If rNeed < 0 Then
            rngCountry.Offset(rNeed).Resize(-rNeed).EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf rNeed = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "No change needed" 'this shouldn't happen unless you did some manual deleting/inserting
        Else
            rng.Copy
            rng.Offset(1).Resize(rNeed).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Old answer:

```
Sub test()
    Dim N As Integer
    N = Range("D10").Value 'merged cells retain the value of the top-left cell of the merge
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("B12:I12") 'adjust if necessary
    rng.EntireRow.Offset(1).Resize(N).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    rng.Offset(1).Resize(N).Value = rng.Value
End Sub
```

Something like that should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The number of rows is perfect. However, whenever I enter a number into D10 the number automatically reverts to 1. Also just a minor thing but is there a way to keep the formatting of row 12 for the created rows? i.e. col F+G and merged and centred; boarders between col C+D, D+E, etc.

Comment: Right, forgot to put the `Target.Value = 1` in the If-clause. That's fixed and I changed the adding of rows to copying the range and inserting the cells instead of full rows. If there would be something next to this range, that'd need more adjusting however.

Answer (score 0):

Place this Sub in the sheet code module, it uses the sheet change event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D10")) Is Nothing Then
  lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
  namecount = False
  For i = 1 To lastrow
    If Cells(i, 2) = "Name" And namecount Then
      Rows(i).Delete
      i = i - 1
    ElseIf Cells(i, 2) = "Name" Then
      namecount = True
    End If
  Next i
If Range("D10") > 0 Then
Rows("13:" & Range("D10") + 12).Insert , Rows(12)
Rows("13:" & Range("D10") + 12).Value = Rows(12).Value
End If

End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

If N=0 then restore the original state. If N>0 then insert N rows below Row(12) and copy it in the insertion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The only problem I'm finding is that after an initial value (N) is entered in D10, and then a new number (M) is re-entered, the number of rows becomes the sum of the two (N+M), whereas it should be M. i.e. the N rows should be deleted before adding the M rows.

Comment: Pls. Check that the `Name` string in the original row(12) hasn't any leading or trailing spaces. If  spaces are necessery then change code line `If Cells(i, 2) = "Name" And namecount Then` to `If Trim(Cells(i, 2)) = "Name" And namecount Then`

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: Copy/Delete Rows

[image]

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const CHANGE_CELL As String = "D10"
    Const MAX_VALUE As Long = 10
    Const FIRST_CELL As String = "B12"
    
    Dim icell As Range: Set icell = Intersect(Me.Range(CHANGE_CELL), Target)
    If icell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim cVal As Variant: cVal = icell.Value
    If Not IsNumeric(cVal) Then Exit Sub
    cVal = CLng(cVal)
    If cVal < 1 Or cVal > MAX_VALUE Then
        MsgBox "Enter an integer between 1 and " & MAX_VALUE & ".", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim fcell As Range: Set fcell = Me.Range(FIRST_CELL)
    
    Dim fStr As String: fStr = CStr(fcell.Value)
    If Len(fStr) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim n As Long: n = 1
    
    Dim nStr As String

    Do
        nStr = CStr(fcell.Offset(n).Value)
        If StrComp(nStr, fStr, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            n = n + 1
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = cVal - n
    If rCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim rrg As Range
    
    With Me.UsedRange
        Set rrg = fcell.Resize(, .Columns( _
            .Columns.Count).Column - fcell.Column + 1)
    End With
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Select Case rCount
        Case Is < 0
            rrg.Offset(cVal).Resize(-rCount).Delete xlShiftUp
        Case Is > 0
            rrg.Copy
            rrg.Offset(n).Resize(rCount).Insert _
                xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End Select

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I get error 1004 that the operation cannot be applied to a merged cell. There seems to be a problem with the line: rrg.Offset(n).Resize(rCount).Insert _
                xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove